# How to share Sitecore caches (item, data, prefetch,etc NOT session state) on Azure PaaS between Web Apps

Tags: azure, caching, performance-optimization, paas

I can't find any docs on this so I assume it's not possible, but...

If you run Sitecore in Azure PaaS and have scale-out enabled (e.g. you're running 2x S3 instances) then can you have a shared/centralized cache, much like the Redis Session State cache?

I'm talking about the built-in `item`, `data`, `prefetch` caches that you can clear from `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`. **Do these have to be stored in-memory on each instance?**

If so, it seems a massive performance problem that each time a new instance spins up it will have to re-create all of those caches from scratch when all the other instances have already done the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of your question “Do these have to be stored in-memory on each instance”?  is “**YES**”

By default, All the Sitecore cache (Item, data, Prefetch, html) are stored in the in-memory/In-Proc of the each server(CM,CD).

But technically it’s possible to implement Redis as output cache and stored the in-memory/In-Proc HTML cache into the output/Out-Proc cache(Redis), Sitecore 8.2 has introduced the abstraction for the cache which makes it possible.

But this implementation has its own limitation which could impact the website performance as well; Martin Ivan explained this limitation in detail, please read this thread for more information:

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/8512#pi214filter=all&pi214scroll=false

Comment: To clarify here - you can _only_ do this for the `HtmlCache` - the Item, Data & Prefech caches are baked into the `Database` object and there is no abstraction for them AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSeal for the clarification..I updated the same.

Comment: Thanks both, I guess this answers my question pretty neatly.

Comment: For performance tuning if patch config created to increase cache size for both master and web db then it's need to be deployed on both CM and CD app services in Azure PaaS?